# Figure position on a title page

Tags: floats

I'm trying to add two images to my thesis title page and I'm failing miserably... The idea is to have the two images in the right and left upper corners of the title page. But the best I managed to obtain was this:

[image]

It looks like the image position is determined by the text underneath it :s. It's a basic problem and I've read a lot of posts on here about figure positioning, but haven't found a solution and I've been stuck with this for hours :(.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)

\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{showframe} % for demo
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
\raggedleft
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{UCL}%
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{EPL}%
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\vfill

\textsc{\LARGE \univname}\\[1.5cm] % University name
\textsc{\Large Master's Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
{\authornames} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]

\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfilment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
%\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
%\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name

{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

\vfill
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Drop the float on the title page, there is no need for it

Comment: Do you want them at the corners of the physical page or at the corners of the text width?

Comment: At the corners of the textwidth. I tried with \textwidth instead of \linewidth but that didn't change anything.

Comment: And ideally I would like the text to be bottom-aligned, thats why I added the \vfill, but again it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? I had to crop a UCL logo found on internet. Note you can change the university logo at the bottom ;o)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, noheadfoot]{geometry}
%
%%\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads »amsmath«
%%\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{showframe} % for demo
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

%\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYzsk.png){b{#1}}
    %\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
    %
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
    \title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

```
\def\univname{Université catholique de Louvain}
\def\HRule{\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}
\def\ttitle{A very very long thesis tile}
\def\authornames{Charles Lutwige Dodgson}
\def\supname{John Tenniel}
\def\degreename{Master in Nonsense}
```

\usepackage{makecell} 
    \begin{document}

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lXr@{}}
\makecell{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{UCL1}}
 & &\makecell{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{EPL}}\\
 \end{tabularx}\\%
  \vfill
  %
  \textsc{\LARGE \univname}\\[1.5cm] % University name
  \textsc{\Large Master's Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

  \HRule \\[0.667cm] % Horizontal line
  {\huge \bfseries \ttitle}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
  \HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
      \emph{Author:}\\
      {\authornames} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
      \emph{Supervisor:} \\
      {\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}%
  \vfill

  \large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfilment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
  \textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
  %\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name
  UPA group\\
  Cartoons Dept\\[2ex]

  {\large \today}\\[1ex] % Date
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{gerald-mcboing-boing} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This kinda works :). But I don't manage to vertically center both images in the \makebox, I'm not even sure if that's possible.

Comment: I made them bottom-aligned, as they seemed to be in the image you posted. I'll change that in a moment.

Comment: Updated: `tabularx` and `makecell` did the trick.

Comment: Apparently some lines of code didn't got properly formatted. I didn't dare to edit your post, but just wanted to let you know.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: You might. Thanks for  pointing it.

Comment: Had to add the makecell package but it works perfectly :D, thanks @Bernard (and to the others too ofc).

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node[anchor=north east] at (current page text area.north east) {\includegraphics[height=0.75in]{epl-logo}};
 \node[anchor=north west] at (current page text area.north west) {\includegraphics[height=0.75in]{UCL-logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{0.75in}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No because the images should be in the corners of the textwidth, not in the corners of the page itself. And same problem as with the previous answer, the images aren't vertically centered relatively to each other.

Comment: The first problem is an easy fix; I'll edit it shortly.  They are equal height, so I'm not sure what you mean by them not being vertically centered.